# Layout cropped on edge curved screen devices

Tags: android, layout

I have a problem with layout being cropped when displaying on screens with curved edges. I have a simple layout with some edittexts and a button. The edittexts are cut off on the left side and it only happens on Samsung Edge devices. Can someone know how to deal with these curved edges screen, because adding larger margins seems like a workaround and on flat screens wouldn't look well .Couldn't find anything useful about the issue,.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 possible solutions to your problem.

1. [WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets): They describe a set of insets for window content. They make it easier to display your UI while taking in to account the system UI and factors of your display.
2. [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline): If you are using a ConstraintLayout as your base layout, using guidelines as your horizontal bounds make it easier to design a responsive UI. For example you could set a horizontal guideline at 0.05 percent and another at 0.95 percent, which would keep you content away from the edges, while also keeping your UI responsive at various screen sizes and densities.